# @ symbol for OWASP supression packageUrl

Tags: maven, owasp

The documentation in https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/general/suppression.html shows how you have the option of matching package url for suppressing a false positive. Where does the '@' come from? Intuitively, I can infer that there will be a version number afterwards, but visiting both https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/11.0.9
and https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/11.0.9/
gives me no clues as to what string it's actually matching against. Is this packageUrl format specific to the dependency check plugin?

```
<suppress>
        <notes><![CDATA[
        This suppresses a CVE identified by OSS Index using the vulnerability name and packageUrl.
        ]]></notes>
        <packageUrl regex="true">^pkg:maven/org\.eclipse\.jetty/jetty-server@.*$</packageUrl>
        <vulnerabilityName>CVE-2017-7656</vulnerabilityName>
    </suppress>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `@` sign separates the package name from its version.

For example

```
^pkg:maven/org\.eclipse\.jetty/jetty-server@2\.3\.14$
```

would specifically refer to only version 2.3.14 of the package, while in your example `@.*` refers to any version of the package.

Comment: Thanks for this! So it looks like the package url is regex. Your example would match the string
`pkg:maven/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server@2.3.14` exactly
which makes sense. Is it hitting some repo of pacakge names expressed in this way? I've never seen it with an `@` symbol before

Comment: It’s a regex because the option `regex="true"` is used in the `packageUrl` tag. The `@` format with the version number is probably in fact specific to the dependency check plugin.